# Razor Expression for Id Behaving differently than expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a new site and I would like to have a specific `id` on the body to dictate what page is open. I am using a Layout view so I'm passing the `id` of each page to the layout using the ViewBag.

I created the Razor expression below to generate the `id` on the body tag but it is not behaving how I expected. I spoke to a co-worker about this and it makes sense to him but I want to understand better why it is producing the output that it is.

I'm confused why this line:

```
<body @(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.PageId) ? String.Format("id=\"{0}\"", ViewBag.PageId) : "")>
```

Produces this:

```
<body id=""str"">
```

But this line:

```
<body @(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.PageId) ? String.Format("id={0}", ViewBag.PageId) : "")>
```

Produces this:

```
<body id="str">
```

I would expect the first to produce `<body id="str">` and the second to produce `<body id=str>` The question pertains to the extra `"`s that are somehow automatically added, where do they come from and why?

The `PageId` is declared like this in the views themselves:

```
@{ ViewBag.PageId = "str"; }
```

Comment: is your `PageId` of type `string` ?

Comment: String escape characters.

Comment: Updated with PageId